# Data Modeling Structure - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I have a project-specific question. I'm trying to determine the most efficient and logical way of setting up my models in my app. The relevant players to model here are: Vendors, Vendor Inventories, and Products. Here is a breakdown of what each item should be able to return in some way:

Inventories:
Store ID
Products and associated details (Price, Name, Brand, Details, Product Code)

Vendors: Store ID, Location, Name

Products: Price, Name, Brand, Details, Product Code

Obviously there is a lot of duplication in this scheme between products and inventories. My issue is that while vendors might have similar items in their inventories, the price will always be different. So I can't simply relate the models by product code. Because most vendors will have the same products, if I were to model store inventories with all of the product information, wouldn't that be a lot of duplication? It's also possible that I don't need to have a separate model for vendors and could just try and keep it all inventories, but I'm lost. Help please?! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is my model structure, though I'm not sure it's ideal.

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :address

    has_one     :inventory
    has_many    :products, through: :inventories
end

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many    :products
    belongs_to  :vendor
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :upc, :brand, :product, :details, :price

    has_many    :inventories
    has_many    :vendors, through: :inventories

end
```

Comment: you should paste some sample model code, would be easier to see the problem. That said, from what I understand vendors and products are a has many to many relationship yes? which means there will be a join table, you could just put the price in the join table, thus have no duplicate products, and unique prices per vendor. depending on the situation, you could probably do away with inventory, well or just call the join table inventory. hope it helps

Comment: I don't really have any sample code yet. I was waiting to generate anything until I could understand the problem a bit more conceptually. Thanks for the tip about the join table. I did some searching and found some good documentation on ActiveRecord associations. We'll see where that leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your specific needs, especially if the set of models are just for example, but judging from the names, here would be my implementation.

A Vendor is the main entity, it will own many products through the join table inventory,

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :address

    has_many     :inventories
    has_many    :products, through: :inventories
end
```

However there are aspects of the product that need to differ between Vendors, in this case, price and quantity( I just made that up), which can be stored in the join table, since it would be independent and made for each product and vendor relationship, is ideal for storing info like price and quantity.

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :product_id, :vendor_id, :price, :quantity

    belongs_to  :product
    belongs_to  :vendor
end
```

Product should only have attributes that would be universal regardless how the vendor handles it, likewise if the product where to be changed, it should be okay with all the vendors.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :upc, :brand, :product, :details

    has_many    :inventories
    has_many    :vendors, through: :inventories

end
```

Doing this you may have difficulties editing this in the view, setting prices and quantity on inventory. Again, my way of doing it would be to use nested fields and interact directly with the join table, and not products, here's some quick partial code using simple_form gem,

on you form,

```
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :inventories do |inventory_fields| %>
      <%= render partial: "inventory_fields", locals: {f: inventory_fields }%>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :f %>
```

and in inventory_fields.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to "Remove", '#', class: "remove_fields btn btn-danger" %>
  <%= f.input :product_id, collection: Product.all.somethingsomething, include_blank: false %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.input :quantity %>
```

Now you can choose your products from a dropdown, and set price and quantity, and whatever you need dynamically.

Comment: Good thoughts Saifis. The models are real. Price will vary by vendor, but there will be no quantities recorded. I'm still having trouble understanding how price and product id can be included in the inventory model. Does that mean that an instance of the inventory class will return price and product id: in a hash or array?

Comment: There will be an inventory instance created for every product a vendor is associated with, that's how join tables work in a has many to many relationship, the join table absorbs all the duplication from Product and Vendor.

Comment: Ah I'm beginning to understand. Does that mean that the inventory model could be more aptly named something like: "inventory_item", because each instance will really contain information for a product + respective vendor information?

Comment: sure, if you want to do it the rails way it would be products_vendors table, which should be plural or not needs to be checked. and you would not need the through or has_many for the join table.